# How to use case statement on shell script linux

Tags: shell

im trying to create a script that check if user already registered before than add number after username for example `username1` and will keep looping after i got unique username.

here what i try

```
username="tes2"
password="tes2"
exists=$(grep -c "^$username:" /etc/passwd)
case=$exists
i=1

while true
do
    case "$case" in
        *)
            echo 'generate new user'
            i=$(( $i + 1 ))
            username="$username""$i"
            exists=$(grep -c "^$username:" /etc/passwd)
            case=$exists;;
        0) 
            pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
            useradd -m -p "$pass" "$username"
            echo 'success add $username' 
            break;;
    esac
done

echo "Quit"
```

when i run this script, it keep `generate new user`.

Comment: Try [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net), it automatically finds problems in scripts like "Line 10: This pattern [always overrides](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2221) a later one on line 16."

Answer (score 5):

https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html

> The commands in the COMMAND-LIST for the *first match* are executed.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs

> `case` will selectively execute the command-list corresponding to the *first* pattern that matches word.

`*` always matches so it's always executed.  If you want the `0` case to execute when it matches, put it before the `*` case.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs would be a much better source to cite.